# How to save a Rational Rose design into an image file

Tags: uml, use-case, rational-rose

I am using `Rational ROse`, and i have created some diagrams. Now i want to save it to an Image. For example `JPG or PNG`.

I couldn't find any option in the tool that allows to do so. Can someone tell me how i could achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select all (Ctrl + A) in Rational Rose, Copy (Ctrl + C) , and open MS paint, Paste (Ctrl + V).

Now save in what ever format you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Rational Rose, but here is how to do it using Rational Software Architect. Chances are that it works with Rational Rose too.

Just select the elements you want to save to an image (or use `Ctrl+A` to select everything), right click and select the `File->Save as image File` menu item. You can choose between several image formats, e.g. PNG, SVG, JPEG, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste would be the simplest solution for a single diagram (Edit/Copy active diagram).
The process can be nicely automated with a Rosebasic Script (see snippet) - the results will be EMF files (Windows Metafile). These can be converted e.g. using InkScape. If you'd like to get a conversion to e.g. SVG / plantUML or other UML tools please contact me personally.

```
'
' Export a diagram and it's view information
'
Sub ExportDiagram(aDiagram As ClassDiagram, ByVal namePrefix As String)

  Dim diagramName As String
  If withDiagramsAsGraphic Then 
     Dim DiagramFile As String
     DiagramFile=ExportDirectory+aDiagram.name+".emf"
     aDiagram.renderEnhanced DiagramFile
  End If 

End Sub
```